# Passing values between classes for Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm working on a small GUI to query information from our CMDB to display for users. The trouble I am having is after an event in one class occurs(button), I want to update a combobox in another class. I thought I should use tk.StringVar() to pass the list, but the combobox only shows a 'PC_VAR#' value and doesn't update. Could anyone offer any assistance please?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import signal


class LoginUI:
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame

        # Set default list entry
        self.dc_list = tk.StringVar()
        self.dc_list.set(['Login first'])

        # Add a button to log in
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Login', command=self.change_combobox)
        self.button.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5)

    def change_combobox(self):
        # Change combobox values
        dc_list = ['Site_1', 'Site_2', 'Site_3']
        self.dc_list.set(dc_list)


class QueryUI:
    def __init__(self, frame, dc_list):
        self.frame = frame
        self.dc = tk.StringVar()
        self.dc_list = tk.StringVar()
        self.dc_list.set(dc_list)

        # Create site combobox
        tk.Label(self.frame, text='Site:').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="w")
        self.dc_combobox = ttk.Combobox(
            self.frame,
            textvariable=self.dc,
            width=20,
            state='readonly'
        )
        self.dc_combobox['values'] = self.dc_list.get()
        self.dc_combobox.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="w")


class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('Logging Handler')
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Create the left frame panels
        left_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, padx=5, pady=5)
        login_frame = tk.LabelFrame(left_frame, text="Login", borderwidth=2, relief="groove", padx=5, pady=5)
        query_frame = tk.LabelFrame(left_frame, text="Query", borderwidth=2, relief="groove", padx=5, pady=5)

        # Align frames
        left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")
        login_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, sticky="nw")
        query_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, sticky="nw")

        # Initialize all frames
        self.login = LoginUI(login_frame)
        self.query = QueryUI(query_frame, self.login.dc_list)
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.quit)
        self.root.bind('<Control-q>', self.quit)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.quit)

    def quit(self, *args):
        self.root.destroy()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We do not need to see all your code. Please create a simple example.

Comment: You really dont want to be using StringVar here. It is not needed.

Comment: Just a comment: You could consider creating your application in Flask too and use HTML,CSS and Javascript as front-end.

Comment: @Anton I thought of that too, and might do it after I finish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do here is pass the controlling class (app) to the class needed to update the combobox. This way we can interact with it later if need be. By passing `self` of `App` to `LoginUI` we can then interact with the class attributes and methods of `App` from within `LoginUI`. This makes it a simple matter to update the combobox.

That said you really don't Need all the StringVars. Just past the list as a list and you will be good to go.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import signal


class LoginUI:
    def __init__(self, controller, frame):
        self.controller = controller
        self.frame = frame
        self.dc_list = ['Login first']
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Login', command=self.change_combobox)
        self.button.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5)

    def change_combobox(self):
        self.controller.query.dc_combobox['values'] = ['Site_1', 'Site_2', 'Site_3']
        self.controller.query.dc.set('Site_1')


class QueryUI:
    def __init__(self, frame, dc_list):
        self.frame = frame
        self.dc = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self.frame, text='Site:').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="w")
        self.dc_combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.frame, textvariable=self.dc, width=20, state='readonly')
        self.dc_combobox['values'] = dc_list
        self.dc_combobox.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="w")


class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('Logging Handler')
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        left_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, padx=5, pady=5)
        login_frame = tk.LabelFrame(left_frame, text="Login", borderwidth=2, relief="groove", padx=5, pady=5)
        query_frame = tk.LabelFrame(left_frame, text="Query", borderwidth=2, relief="groove", padx=5, pady=5)
        left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")
        login_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, sticky="nw")
        query_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5, sticky="nw")
        self.login = LoginUI(self, login_frame)
        self.query = QueryUI(query_frame, self.login.dc_list)
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.quit)
        self.root.bind('<Control-q>', self.quit)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.quit)

    def quit(self, *args):
        self.root.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried not using StringVar() but it was passing 'self' to the LoginUI class that seemed to be the key. Thank you!

Comment: As a side question, what value does using StringVar() bring over just setting a str() or list()?

Comment: @Rjin StringVar is good for when you need multiple fields to update at once. For example if you have multiple labels updating. Or say you need a variable to update automatically then StringVar is useful along with the other variable types like IntVar and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the help!